# Update a column with different data based on the Primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to update a table but the problem I have is the following: I have a table with more than 60K primary keys in a column called `TerminalID`. This table has like 10 more columns, but I would like to update a column called `SerialNumber`, but the problem is that the serial number is not the same for every primary key.

The problem is that the update SQL code below will apply the same serial number to all the `terminalID`'s I have and not a different to each PK.

Any idea?

```
Use [testserver]

update [testtable]
set SerialNumber =''
from [testtable]
where [TerminalID] in ( ... )


terminalID    Serial Number
463328        215728108
168734        213808561
160879        214621937
451991       215523741
```

This is the only way I can think now , do it one by one

```
Update [terminalsetting] SET [SerialNumber] ='766' WHERE [TerminalID] ='63872'
Update [terminalsetting] SET [SerialNumber] ='215728108' WHERE [TerminalID] ='463328'
Update [terminalsetting] SET [SerialNumber] ='213808561' WHERE [TerminalID] ='168734'
```

Comment: You could create a temporary table / cte / values clause with the TerminalId and Serial number you want and update using a join

Comment: Please provide sample data and explain how the value for `SerialNumber` is determined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-to-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)

Comment: I've added part of the 4000k Terminal IDs I need to update and what will be the serial number . So far the only thing I can think is the code I added at the end

Answer (score 0):

I would say use rownumber column and CTE. This will give you a unique number for each row.
Then using this number and update your table.

Read this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql